# .Net Core display DataMember name in Swagger

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, attributes, swagger

I have a request of displaying the name from DataMember attribute in the request body of Swagger, instead of displaying the property name. 
For example, I have the `Test` class as below:

```
  [DataContract]
  public abstract class Test
  {
      [DataMember(Name = "my_test")]
      public Object MyTest{ get; set; }
  }
```

In the swagger request body, currently it's dispalying `myTest`, which is the name of property. But, I'd like to display `my_test`. 
Does anyone have any idea how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decorate with a property name like so:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class Test
{
    [DataMember(Name = "my_test")]
    [JsonPropertyName("my_test")]
    public Object MyTest { get; set; }
}
```